# Currency Problem With Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi i have developed crystal report in asp.net web site
i want to set currency format like 1,20,000 (Indian Currency) but right now currency take My Server Hosted Currency Format and i was working for indian company so i there any format to convert currency in indian format for crystal report//

Answer (score 1):

```
-- You can use below said code to your report part;

CStr({@FieldName}, "##,##,##,###.##")

And you are working for Indian Company, you will needed in words also. To write in words, use below said code;

numbervar RmVal:=0; 
numbervar Amt:=0; 
numbervar pAmt:=0; 
stringvar InWords :="Rupees "; 

Amt := {@FieldName}  ; 


if Amt > 10000000 then RmVal := truncate(Amt/10000000); 
if Amt = 10000000 then RmVal := 1; 

   if RmVal = 1 then 
        InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " crore" 
   else 
        if RmVal > 1 then InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " crores"; 


    Amt := Amt - Rmval * 10000000; 

    if Amt > 100000 then RmVal := truncate(Amt/100000); 
    if Amt = 100000 then RmVal := 1; 

    if RmVal = 1 then 
        InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " lakhs"
    Else
        If RmVal > 1 then InWords := InWords + " " + ToWords(RmVal,0) + " Lakhs";

        Amt := Amt - Rmval * 100000; 

        if Amt > 0 then InWords := InWords + " " + towords(truncate(Amt),0); 

        pAmt := (Amt - truncate(Amt)) * 100; 

        if pAmt > 0 then 
            InWords := InWords + " and " + towords(pAmt,0) + " paisa only" 
        else 
            InWords := InWords + " only"; 

        ProperCase(InWords)
```